# AppCrash when trying to install Skype

Tags: windows-7, skype

I am trying to install Skype 5.5 for Windows, but I keep getting a crash in the installer program. I first tried the small (900k) auto-download installer, which failed. I then downloaded the SkypeSetupFull.exe full installer, but whenever I try and run it, I get a Windows error dialogue saying: "Skype has stopped working", with the 'check online', 'close', and 'debug' options. The problem details shown in the dialogue are:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   SkypeSetupFull.exe
Application Version:    5.5.0.124
Application Timestamp:  4e96cbf7
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7600.16385
Fault Module Timestamp: 4a5bdadb
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0006a7c9
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  7177
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have searched online quite extensively with no joy. What can I try to fix, or at least diagnose, this issue? I am running Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the [beta](http://skype.com/go/getskype-beta) version, with which many people have had better luck.